# Access other class functions inside a promise's callback

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a class called *Reel* that has 2 functions. Inside one of them I'm defining a new promise and trying to access the other function from inside its callback. However the other function is *undefined*. Here's the relevant code:

```
class Reel {
  constructor(reelContainer, idx, initialSymbols) {
    // some code here
  }

  spin() {
    const animationPromise = new Promise(resolve => this.animation.onfinish = resolve);
    const timeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log('debug here...');
      console.log(this);
      console.log(this.fetchResults());
      this.fetchResults().then(() => {
        console.log('got results from the backend...');
        resolve();
      });


      // setTimeout(resolve, this.regularGameFactor * 1000);
    });
    // som other code here
  }

  fetchResults() {
    // some code here...
    resolve();
  }
}
```

I see that this has the value of instance of `Reel`, however `this.fethResults()` is undefined.

Comment: Please post your actual code, or code that demonstrates the problem properly.

Comment: There is no `resolve` variable defined in `fetchResults()`. Also it doesn't have a `return` statement either, so it's normal that `this.fetchResults()` would return `undefined`. And you haven't defined `this.animation` anywhere in the code so your `animationPromise` would be broken as well.

Answer (score -1):

ok, if i have you understand correcly, you want basically to call

```
this.fethResults()
```

This can be done by declaring a variable and assign the reference "this" to this variable and then you can make the call inside the promise

```
var self = this; //outside of the promise
self.fethResults() //inside the promise
```

Comment: This isn't necessary.